# Unable to extract data using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to extract Pre open stock market data of NSE(India). I'm able to fetch the data from the scrapy shell but when I run it as a file or run it in pycharm as a whole code I'm not getting any output. My code is

```
class PreopenMarketDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'preopen_market_data'
    allowed_domains = ['www1.nseindia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/pre_open_market/pre_open_market.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        stocks = ['RELIANCE', 'TATASTEEL', 'LT']
        for stock in stocks:
            stock_url  = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/pre_open/preOpenOrderBook.jsp?param='+str('stock')+'EQN&symbol='+str('stock')
            yield Request(stock_url, callback=self.data)
    def data(self,response):
        p=response.xpath('//*[@class="orderBookFontCBig"]/text()').extract()
        yield Request(p,callback=self,meta={'Stock':p})
```

Why is it not fetching the data. What am I doing wrong here? Can we do this via formRequest method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yield Request(p,callback=self,meta={'Stock':p})`. This isn't how you yield output on scrapy. This is telling it to visit the url 1975.00 and if successful try to call self, which is a nonsense instruction. I'm kinda surprised that it's not throwing some kind of error.

What you want to do is create an item, put the stock value into it and yield that at item.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line just print p to get the output data.

```
class PreopenMarketDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
        name = 'preopen_market_data'
        allowed_domains = ['www1.nseindia.com']
        start_urls = ['https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/pre_open_market/pre_open_market.htm']
    
        def parse(self, response):
            stocks = ['RELIANCE', 'TATASTEEL', 'LT']
            for stock in stocks:
                stock_url  = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/pre_open/preOpenOrderBook.jsp?param='+stock+'EQN&symbol='+stock
                yield Request(stock_url, callback=self.data)
    
        def data(self,response):
            p=response.xpath('//*[@class="orderBookFontCBig"]/text()').extract()
            print(p)
            # yield Request(p,callback=self,meta={'Stock':p}) 
print output 
['1975.00']
['526.00']
```